# How do I destroy eight Aurum Core guns?

Tags: kid-icarus-uprising

One of the Treasure Hunt items reads

> Chapter 15: Destroy 8 of the Aurum Core's guns

I just finished the boss fight on intensity 6.0 and there were only six guns. I blew them up right away and waited a few minutes, but more didn't appear. I also triggered the second stage of the boss, when it starts flashing red, but none reappeared then either.

How do I destroy eight guns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I remember, you need to play it at a higher intensity. Also, there are guns by the core and behind you on the walls as well.

Comment: I tried at 7.5, died and kept playing at 6.5, and this time the guns respawned after the core started flashing red. I guess it's probably like Thanatos where you need to play at 6.1+.

Comment: There are more guns on the other side of the core, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Around the walls, not just on the core, there are more guns everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I played at 3.4. Once you destroy the first 6 guns, hit the core until everything goes red. After a minute or so, 6 more guns should appear, destroy them all, just in case.